# Javascript on local machine - How to disable restrictions without changing security settings on Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am creating a very simple html page using very basic javascript **meant to only be run locally and with any Internet Explorer browser**.

And by very simple I mean as in I built house with popsicle sticks and mud (javascript) knowing perfectly well that bricks and cement is what I should be using (php or jquery etc.).

The intent of the script is so that when a submit button is pressed, it's would generate a pop-up displaying a bunch of text.  The problem is that every time I've tried, I get the message "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls."

Pressing the "Allow block content" button only shows the message no matter how many times I've pressed it.  I've attempted to "view source," but the only thing displayed is "`<HTML></HTML>`"

Here's a snippet of my script:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function formSubmit() {
//Something exciting happens....
    generatePopup();
}
function generatePopup() {
    var pop = open("", "Popup", "width=300,height=200");
    var text = ""
    var txt = ""

    for (var x = 0 ; x < 10; x++) {
        text = text + " a" + x + "\r\n"
    }

    txt = pop.document.createTextNode(text);

    pop.document.body.appendChild(txt)
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<P><INPUT type="button" onclick="return formSubmit()" value="Submit form"></P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Is there any way to get around that without going to the Tools menu on Internet Explorer and "Disable Automatic prompting for ActiveX controls"?

Comment: Do you have `<script>` tags anywhere?

Comment: My money is on "you can't." It's a security restriction, it wouldn't be very secure if a webpage could just get around it,

Answer (score 2):

Try the following header:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
<html>
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx) you have full description of that feature.

Comment: Will that help? The docs say it can't be used to make a page *less* restricted.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to add that to the popup itself.  Or did you mean that adding to the main page allow this?

Comment: Also, I've tried putting this on the main page.  It removes the "restricted" from displaying on the main page BUT the pop-up doesn't appear at all.  IE doesn't even show the "pop-up has been blocked message."  Any idea how to append those two lines into the popup?